# is it clear, grammatical and idiomatic to use "neither can be"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I am adding some comments on this line of code.

```
# param winname cannot be null, neither can be empty string ''
imshow(winname, mat) -> None
```

in this case, is it clear, grammatical and idiomatic to use "neither can be"?

Comment: No - *cannot be null or an empty string* is what I'd put. If you wanted to use *neither* in that position you'd have to say something like *cannot be null; neither can it be an empty string* - but this is not a suitable style for a comment in some code.

Comment: The answers suggest good corrections so I won’t add another one, but in that comment you’re confusing *neither* and *nor* - *nor* is like *or* for a list of negative things (a list of things that are excluded):

Comment: No - *neither* also has that function. *Nor* would be a more likely choice, for sure, but the Q is about *neither*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use is not clear. You have a few options:

- param winname cannot be null nor can it be an empty string.
- param winname can be neither null nor an empty string.
- If possible (and I don't know if it is) I'd make this into a positive statement (something like param winname must be a XXX, but I don't know what XXX would be).

Although this is a comment, it also looks a bit like an error message. If so, I'd make it into two error messages, one for each case.

- param winname cannot be null
- param winname cannot be an empty string